# Using older version of JDK8 after January, 2019

Tags: licensing

I'm using Oracle JDK8 for some web services and it's a bit difficult to move to OpenJdk right now.

As public support for JDK8 is ending on January, 2019, is it possible continue using Oracle JDK8 without further update for commercial purposes?
Or  does a user need to subscribe to new model even though that user doesn't want to update?

Comment: You're obviously not legally obligated by Oracle to update your own use of JDK8. It's your choice. Read the TOS for JDK8; you release Oracle from any liability.

Comment: This isn't in my view a request for specific legal advice, it is a question about whether a particular action is or is not allowed under the law, and is therefore on-topic.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Yes, I'm not obligated to update, nor oracle is liable for any issue as per [BCL](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/index.html). The question is if I can continue using old version under old license or not.

Comment: @Sarowar what does the license say - if anything - about using the old version under the old license?

Comment: @BlueDogRanch That's what I can't figure out! :( I was going through oracle faqs but this point seems very obscure.

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/oracle-java-se-releases-faq question 5 helps?